# pattern-match on big type, a way to reduce the size of the code

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Let’s say I have a new « big » type. 
For example let’s say I have the type « formule » :

```
    type formule =
   |VRAI
   |Predicat of char
   |NON of formule
   |ET of formule * formule
   |OU of formule * formule
   |X of formule
   |G of formule
   |F of formule
   |U of formule * formule
```

Now I want a function that calculates the size of a type « formule ». In order to do so we can use the same algorithm that calculates the number of nodes of a binary tree. The problem here is that if I do a pattern matching I have to handle a lot of cases and this is annoying.

It would be great if I can pattern-match on the number of argument just like the following « taille » function :

```
  let rec taille = function
  |VRAI || Predicat(_) -> 1
  |_(a) -> 1 + taille a
  |_(a,b) -> 1 + taille a + taille b
```

The problem is that this doesn’t work. When I compile the following code :

```
type formule =
   |VRAI
   |Predicat of char
   |NON of formule
   |ET of formule * formule
   |OU of formule * formule
   |X of formule
   |G of formule
   |F of formule
   |U of formule * formule

let rec taille = function
  |VRAI || Predicat(_) -> 1
  |_(a) -> 1 + taille a
  |_(a,b) -> 1 + taille a + taille b
```

I get the following error :

```
File "main.ml", line 1, characters 192-195:
Error: Syntax error
```

I think it comes from my pattern-matching which is incorrect, yet in this case why I have a error on the first line ?

Moreover, if it does come from my pattern-matching is there a way to do a pattern-matching just as « taille » does (pattern-matching on the number of argument in order to reduce the number of cases).

Thank you !

Comment: The error message is very strange, OCaml seems to think that the whole program is written on one line. Which editor are you using? Are you working on Windows?

Comment: You are right. Actually it comes from the fact that copy and paste the code from a pdf file. That’s why the editor think the whole program is written on a single line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the binary disjunction operator in a pattern like that. There is, however, a pattern matching shortcut that does what you want:

```
let rec taille = function
  | VRAI | Predicat _ -> 1
  | NON a | X a | G a | F a -> 1 + taille a
  | ET (a, b) | OU (a, b) | U (a, b) -> 1 + taille a + taille b
```

The cases for one and two arguments are not as succinct as you would like, but I do not think it is possible to do any better. You cannot use a wildcard (`_`) on constructors.

Another idea would be to capture the "extract arguments" pattern in an auxiliary function:

```
let args = function
  | VRAI | Predicat _ -> []
  | NON a | X a | G a | F a -> [a]
  | ET (a, b) | OU (a, b) | U (a, b) -> [a; b]
```

And then you could write:

```
let rec taille f = List.fold_left (fun a x -> a + taille x) 1 (args f)
```

Or, without the intermediate lists:

```
let fold_args f1 f2 c =
  let rec g = function
    | VRAI | Predicat _ -> c
    | NON a | X a | G a | F a -> f1 (g a)
    | ET (a, b) | OU (a, b) | U (a, b) -> f2 (g a) (g b)
  in
  g

let taille = fold_args (fun x -> 1 + x) (fun x y -> 1 + x + y) 1
```

Comment: Thank you ! It does perfectly answer my question. Yet why I can't use the disjunction operator here ?

Comment: The context requires a [pattern](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html), and `||` is an [infix operator](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/names.html#infix-op) in an [expression](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html). In any case, `||` is of type `bool -> bool -> bool` (not `formule -> formule -> ?`).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would refactor the type `formule` like this:

```
type infix = ET | OU | U

type prefix = NON | X | G | F

type formule =
  | VRAI
  | Predicat of char
  | Infix of formule * infix * formule
  | Prefix of prefix * formule
```

I don't know the domain you're working with, but I imagine this is some sort of language with prefix and infix operators.

Then you can write the `taille` function like this:

```
let rec taille = function
  | VRAI | Predicat _ -> 1
  | Prefix (_, a) -> 1 + taille a
  | Infix (a, _, b) -> 1 + taille a + taille b
```

Now that your types are more granular you might discover new functions that makes sense on the new types.